# How to find the address of the contract owner?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, testing

I'm under the impression that the owner of the contract is simply referred to as `accounts[0]` in Truffle's testing environment, but I'm getting the error by the modifier that the caller of a certain function is not the owner.

I have instantiated contract `A` and contract `B` and the following code is in contract `B`:

```
    modifier requireContractOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "Caller is not contract owner");
        _;
    }

    function _authorizeCaller(address addr)
        external
        requireContractOwner
    {
        authorizedCaller[addr] = true;
    }
```

And I'm calling the functions from contract `A`:

```
    function authorizeCaller(address addr) public {
        B._authorizeCaller(addr);
    }
```

The way I instantiated `A` is:

```
    constructor(address dataContract) public {
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
        B = B(dataContract);
    }
```

and `B`:

```
   constructor() public {
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
        authorizedCaller[msg.sender] = true;
    }
```

Following is how I deploy them:

```js
module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(B).then(() => {
    return deployer
      .deploy(A, B.address)
      .then(() => {
       // configuration
      });
  });
};
```

The problem is, when I test calling the function with the owner of the contract:

```js
      let B = await B.new();
      let A = await A.new(B.address);
      await A.authorizeCaller(accounts[1], {
        from: accounts[0],
        gasPrice: 0,
      });
```

the testing fails saying that `accounts[0]` is not the owner of the contract by the modifier `requireContractOwner()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that the owner of the contract is simply referred to as `accounts[0]` in Truffle's testing environment...

Unless you explicitly specify `{from: someAccount}`, the default is indeed `{from: accounts[0]}`.

---

> And I'm calling the functions from contract `A`:

```
function authorizeCaller(address addr) public {
    B._authorizeCaller(addr);
}
```

Here, the value of `msg.sender` when function `_authorizeCaller` is executed will be the address of contract `A`, not the address of the deployer of contract `A`.

Hence the expression `msg.sender == contractOwner` will evaluate to `false`.

You should generally implement the `requireContractOwner` modifier in a utility contract:

```
contract Owned {
    address public contractOwner;

    constructor() public {
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier requireContractOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "Caller is not contract owner");
        _;
    }
}
```

And then inherit this contract and use it wherever needed:

```
import "./Owned.sol";

contract B is Owned {
    constructor() public {
        // constructor of `Owned` has already executed at this point
        ...
    }

    function _authorizeCaller(address addr) external requireContractOwner {
        ...
    }
}
```